# How can I rearrange the windows of the same program on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

In Windows 7, I have the taskbar buttons set to not combine, so I often have multiple Google Chrome browser buttons side by side.

Is there a way to rearrange those buttons around each other? When I try to click and drag, all the chrome buttons get dragged together and can be moved around the other taskbar buttons, but I can't move a single button around the others.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this with third party software called [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). Windows 7 doesn't have any means to do what you want out of the box.